# Cantgive access to my webcam on websites

Tags: 12.04, flash, webcam

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. When I try to use websites that access my webcam (ustream for example), the dialog where you allow access is not clickable. (see image) [image]

I have the latest flash player installed, have cleared my cache,nothing seems to fix it. It works fine on my Mint machine (which is the exact same model laptop - HP Envy6).
Any cles how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is simple I have found. Open the window on ustream, youtube or whatever site you are using. when the flash settings dialog appears, right click on it. This will take you to settings manager. Next, click on the privacy settings icon. You will see a list of sites you have been to. Find the site you want to use to access tyour cam & click "always allow". Restart your browser & try again.